# To what extent did d'Alembert want to avoid the newtonian concept of force?

Tags: physics

The context of this question:

In everyday life we use push and pull all the time to get things moving, to move ourselves. To ride a bicycle: our feet push the pedals to get moving. To accelerate we increase the magnitude of the push.

In the time that Huygens and Newton did their work the magnitude of push & pull that is involved in acceleration was hardly accessible to measurement, if at all.

Huygens created setups where he would have pendulum bobs collide with each other. To my understanding: Huygens was able to make bobs sufficiently hard and elastic such that he got very close to perfect elastic collision.

Let me refer to a setup with two pendulum bobs as a setup with $b_1$ and $b_2$

To my understanding: a typical setup would be one where $b_1$ is released from a height $h_1$. With two bobs of equal mass $b_1$ would come to a dead stop, and $b_2$ would swing up to the same height as the initial height of $b_1$. With bobs of unequal mass $b_1$ still has motion after the elastic collision. If the respective bobs would swing back up to consistent height then that is what Huygens could measure with consistency.

My understanding is that the data that Huygens had access to was the kind of data that can be obtained with setups like that. The *height* to which a bob swings back up is an indirect measure of the velocity imparted to it on collision.

Pendulum experiments

The period of pendulum swing depends on two factors: the length of the pendulum, and the gravitatinal acceleration. Gravitational mass and inertial mass are equivalent, so pendulums with bobs of different mass but equal length (from pivot point to center of mass of the bob) will have equal period of swing.

The equivalence of gravitational and inertial mass was extremely helpful to the development of celestial mechanics. If gravitational mass and inertial mass are equivalent then it is not necessary to know the masses of the various planets of the solar system.

On the other hand, the equivalence of gravitational and inertial mass means that while you know the gravitational *acceleration* you don't necessarily know the gravitational force.

To assign a value to gravitational force we need a standard unit of mass. But the only way to set up a standard unit of mass is to create a reproducible volume of a reproducible substance, and to measure the weight of that.

It could be, I don't know, that d'Alembert saw circular reasoning in that.

Today we have classroom demonstrations with an air track. The students can calibrate some elastic force, use that elastic force to accelerate a glider, record video of the motion, and then obtain the acceleration data from the video.

The question:

Is my following understanding correct:
The aim of d'Alembert was to develop a mechanics with no explicit use of push & pull. Instead everything was to be described in terms of change of quantity of motion. The concepts of potential energy and kinetic energy were not yet in their current form of course, what d'Alembert used was precursors to those concepts, but that is what d'Alembert used.

From an outside perspective it seems very strange that d'Alembert would want to avoid the newtonian concept of force. In everyday life we use push & pull all the time to get around.

Hence my question:
To what extent did d'Alembert want to avoid the newtonian concept of force?

Comment: But where does d'Alembert comes from in this long post?

Comment: But yes, d'Alembert was a "leibnizian" and thus he strongly disagree with Newton's approach to e.g. space and gravity. In the *Traité* (page xxi) d'Alembert called *force* "'a term used to express an effect". See also page xxv about the "terme obscur de *force*".

Comment: The *Traité* has the *force d'inertie* (page 3) and the "impulsion" (page 16). Then he introduce the *force accélératrice* as a definition: $\varphi dt = du$